# Locally compact Hausdorff topological vector spaces are finite-dimensional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

It's an important fact that locally compact Hausdorff topological vector spaces are finite-dimensional, a proof can be found [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/locally-compact-topological-vector-spaces/). I'm somewhat stuck with the proof.

> If ${U}$ is a neighbourhood of the origin. then for every ${x \in V}$ we see that ${2^{-n} x \in U}$ for sufficiently large ${n}$. By compactness of ${K}$ (and continuity of the scalar multiplication map at zero), we conclude that ${2^{-n} K \subset U}$ for some sufficiently large ${n}$.

Here $K$ is a compact neighborhood of the origin, From the above argument, I know that for every $x\in K$, we have $x\in 2^n U$ sufficiently large $n$, then by the compactness of $K$, we can find a finite collection of sets $\{2^{n_1}U,\cdots,2^{n_k}U\}$ such that 
$$K\subset 2^{n_1}U\cup\cdots\cup 2^{n_k}U.$$
But how can we say there exists a $n$ such that $K\subset 2^nU$?

Comment: You can take $n$ to be the maximum of $n_1,\cdots,n_k$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Could you say it more clearly? I don't know how to use the fact you mentioned.

Comment: Because if $2^n<2^m$ then $2^nU\subset 2^mU$. So $\cup_n^N 2^nU = 2^N U$

Comment: @s.harp Why $n<m$ implies $2^nU\subset 2^mU$? I don't see it obviously.

Comment: @Rise You use that fact that $sU\subset tU$ for $s\leq t$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following fact - Every neighbourhood of $0$ contains a balanced neighbourhood of $0$. (Rudin Functional analysis theorem 1.14)

By a balanced set we mean a set $B$ such that $\alpha B\subseteq B$ for every scalar $\alpha$ such that $|\alpha|\le1$.

So WLOG let $U$ be balanced.

Now if $s\le t\Longrightarrow\dfrac{s}{t}\le1\Longrightarrow\dfrac{s}{t}U\subseteq U\Longrightarrow sU\subseteq tU$.

That is all that you need here.

Comment: Do we must use that fact? Since Tao doesn't mention it

Comment: The link you gave says to use the continuity of scalar multiplication. Proving the fact I mentioned also requires the use of continuity of scalar multiplication so I am guessing that you are required to prove this fact here

Comment: The fact has a short proof (see, for instance, Theorem 3 in "[Functional Analysis](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c33c/2a204591f068b2f8e0bb85239f6ed99ee978.pdf)" by Huiqiang Jiang). Let $U$ be any  open neighborhood of the zero. Since scalar multiplication is continuous, exists $\delta > 0$, and an open neighborhood $V$ of the zero such that $\alpha V \subset U$ whenever $|\alpha| <\delta$. Then $W=\bigcup_{|\alpha|<\delta} \alpha V$ is balanced and $W\subset U$.