# Is the set of all monic polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ with roots in a compact set $K$ compact?

Tags: polynomials, roots, compactness, normed-spaces

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $T$ a bounded operator in a Hilbert space $H$ (or an element of a unital Banach algebra $B$).

1. Does there exist a norm on $\mathbb{C}[X]$ such that the set of all
   monic polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ with roots in the compact set
   $K$ is compact ?
2. Is the set $\{P(T) :  \text{P a monic polynomial in
   } \mathbb{C}[X] \text{ with roots in the compact set } K \}$ compact
   in $B(H)$ (or $B$)?

I tried to use the map $\phi$ from $(K^\mathbb{N})_0$ (finite sequences of elements of $K$) to $\mathbb{C}[X]$ (or $B(H)$) defined by $\phi((\rho_n)_{n=1}^m) = \prod_{n=1}^m (X-\rho_n)$ or ($\prod_{n=1}^m (T-\rho_n)$) but I failed to show that it is continuous or that $(K^\mathbb{N})_0$ is compact.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouché%27s_theorem might help

Comment: I guess $B(H)$ is the algebra of all bounder linear operators from $H$ to $H$, right? Which topology (or norm) do you consider on $B(H)$?

Answer (score 3):

Since $K$ is compact the coefficients of the corresponding polynomials are bounded.
On the other side if we consider a converging sequence of polynomials, if their coefficients are close then the corresponding roots are close, which would make the roots of the limit polynomial contained in $K$ due to the compactness of $K$.

EDIT: This would only work if the degree is fixed. Still I'll leave the answer as some might find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

$\def\CC{\mathbb{C}}$Regarding (1): If you want "coefficient of $X^1$" to be a continuous function with respect to your norm, then no. All the polynomials $(X+1)^n$ have roots in the unit disc, so the coefficient of $X^1$ (namely $n$) is not bounded on this set, so this set cannot be compact.

---

On the other hand, if $K$ is contained in the closed ball of radius $r$ around $0$, for some $r<1$, and if you include the $0$ polynomial in your set, then I can do it. Specifically,
let $f_0 + f_1 X + \cdots + f_{n-1} X^{n-1} + f_n X^n$ be the coefficients of a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[X]$. Choose a positive real number $s$ with $s<1-r$. My norm will be
$$\sum_k s^{2k} |f_k|^2 = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\theta=0}^{2 \pi} |f(s e^{i \theta})|^2 d \theta. \qquad (\clubsuit)$$
It is important that I include the $0$ polynomial in my set: We have $\lim_{n \to \infty} X^n = 0$. I can't think of anything else that I would want as an accumulation point of the sequence $(X^n)$, so I think this is non-negotiable.

Note that the restriction of $(\clubsuit)$ to the polynomials of degree $\leq n$ gives the standard topology on $\CC^{n+1}$.

Let $S_n \subset \CC[X]$ be the set of degree $n$ monic polynomials with roots in $K$. The map $K^n \to \CC^n$ sending $(\rho_1, \rho_2, \ldots, \rho_n)$ to the coefficients of $\prod (X+\rho_i)$ is continuous, so each $S_n$, being the image of compact set under a continuous map, is compact. We want to show that $\bigcup_n S_n \cup \{ 0 \}$ is compact. To this end, it is enough to show that, if $f^i(X) \in S_{n_i}$ is any sequence of polynomials with $n_i \to \infty$, then $\lim f^i(X) =0$.

This is not hard at all. Let $f(X) = \prod (X+\rho_i)$ be a polynomial of degree $x$. If $z$ is on the circle $|z|=s$ and the $\rho_i$ are in the disc of radius $r$, then we have
$$|f(z)|^2 \leq \prod_i (|z|+|\rho_i|)^2 = |s+r|^{2n}.$$
So the average value of $|f|^2$ on the circle of radius $s$ is bounded by $|s+r|^{2n}$.
As we took $s<1-r$, this goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: The proof by integration reveals that there is a lot of flexibility in the choice of norm. We could use $\int |f|^2 \mu$ where $\mu$ is any measure supported in the interior of the disc of radius $1-r$ around $0$. If $K$ were contained in a disc of radius $r$ around some other point $a$, we could instead use a measure supported within a disc of radius $1-r$ around $a$. But it seems to be crucial not to let $K$ be too large.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding (1). What about if we do not suppose that some coefficient functional is continuous? Do you have a strong argument to tackle that case too? Concerning your second argument, correct me if I am wrong, but adding the zero polynomial to the inverse set of polynomials with roots in K seems unnecessary, since it may be conceivable to take this limit to be the polynomial 1, which is already in the inverse set of polynomials with roots in K. Can we construct a norm having the main property, plus the property $X^n \to 1$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\tilde K$ be the set of all monic polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ with roots in the set $K$.
Let $r>1$ be any number.
Put $B_r=\{z\in\mathcal C:|z|\le r\}$.
Let $P\in \mathbb{C}[X]$ be any polynomial.
Let $d$ be degree of $P$ and $M$ be the maximal absolute value of a coefficient of $P$.
Pick any natural $n$ such that $r^n>M(d+1)$.
Pick $Q(z)=z^{n+d}+P(z)$.
Let $z\in\mathbb C\setminus B_r$ be any complex number.
Then $$|Q(z)|\ge |z|^{n+d}- M(d+1)|z|^d=|z|^d(|z|^n-M(d+1))\ge |z|^d(r^n- M(d+1))>0.$$
So all roots of $Q$ are in $B_r$, that is $Q\in \widetilde{B_r}$ and $P\in \widetilde{B_r}-z^{n+d}$.

Suppose that $\widetilde{B_r}$ is compact.
Then $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is covered by countably many compact sets.
Suppose for a contradiction that $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is complete.
By the Baire category theorem, $\mathbb{C}[X]$ contains a compact set with nonempty interior.
So $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is a locally compact normed space.
Then $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is finitely dimensional (see, for instance, the beginning of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157184/properties-of-topological-vector-spaces/3272356#3272356) my answer), a contradiction.

Maybe a similar construction can be done for Banach algebras.

Unfortunately, when $\mathbb{C}[X]$ then there is no contradiction similarly the case of complete $\mathbb C[X]$, because there exist $\sigma$-compact infinitely dimensional normed spaces, for instance, the subspace of $\ell^2$ consisting of the sequences which are eventually zero. (2)

2. Let $(B,\|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach algebra, $T\in B$, and
   $$\widetilde{K}=\{P(T):P  \mbox{ is a monic polynomial in } \mathbb{C}[X] \text{ with roots in } K \}.$$

Then $\widetilde{K}$ is a topological semigroup with respect to the multiplication. Let $R$ be any element of $\widetilde{K}$.
For each natural $n$ put $[R_n]=\{R^m:m\in\mathbb N,\,m\ge n\}$. Then $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\overline{[R_n]}$ is a compact group,
see [Num] and [Sch], so it contains an idempotent $e$. So $e\in\widetilde{K}$.

Suppose that $\|e\|<1$. If $\|e\|>0$ then $\|e\|=\|e\|\cdot \|e\|<\|e\|$, which is impossible. So $e=0$.
On the other hand, $e\in\widetilde{K}$ so either there exists a monic polynomial $P\in\mathbb{C}[X]$  with roots in $K$ such that $P(T)=e=0$ or we consider the zero of $\mathbb{C}[X]$ as a polynomial with roots in $K$.

*References*

[Num] Katsumi Numakura, *On bicompact semigroups*, Mathematical Journal of Okayama University **1** (1952) 99-108.

[Sch] Štefan Schwarz, *K teorii Hausdorfovyh bicompaktnyh polugrupp* *(On Hausdorff bicompact semigroups),
Czechoslovak Mathematical Journal, **5**:80 (1955) 1-23.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Regarding (1). What about if we do not suppose that $(\mathbb{C}[X], \lVert \rVert)$ is complete? Do you have a strong argument to tackle that case too? Regarding (2), you said "to avoid a contradiction we have to assume that e is a polynomial." I don't understand this step. Is it related to the fact that $(\lVert e \rVert^n )$ is increasing in the case $\lVert e \rVert \geq 1$?

Comment: @JeyromeSapin I updated the answer explaining these issues.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Regarding your comment "Unfortunately, when C[X], then there is no contradiction": is it the case that there exists a suitable norm in this complementary case ? Could you propose one ? Moreover, are you assuming that e=0 in the case $\lVert e \rVert > 1$ too ?

Comment: @JeyromeSapin Hmm, it seems here is a terra incognita, where are not applicable both my impossibility proof and David E Speyer's [norm construction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744153/is-the-set-of-all-monic-polynomials-in-mathbbcx-with-roots-in-a-compact-s/4789894#4789894),
which requires that $K$ is contained in the ball of radius $r<1$ around $0$. Of course, when $\|e\|>1$ then $e$ cannot be the zero.