# When is a weak* Cauchy sequence of measures convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\{ \mu_k \}$ be a sequence of regular Borel measures on some locally compact topological space $X$, which is *Cauchy*, in the sense that for any $f \in C_c(X)$, $\{ \int fd\mu_k \}$ is a Cauchy sequence of numbers. One condition guaranteeing that $\{ \mu_k \}$ converges weakly is that the measures $\mu_k$ have uniformly bounded total variation, so we can apply the Banach Alaoglu theorem. But what condition guarantees that there exists a regular Borel measure $\mu$ such that $\mu_k \to \mu$ weakly, if the measures are allowed to be infinite. For simplicity, we can assume $X = \mathbf{R}^d$ for some $d$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're disregarding the [Banach-Alaoglu theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem), which states that the closed unit ball of $X^*$ is compact in the weak $*$ topology, where $X$ is a normed space. Borel regular measures correspond to functionals in $X^*$. Your Cauchy sequence will then converge to a continuous functional, and the [Riesz Markov-Kakutani theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) will give you this limit functional stems from some Borel regular measure. So given that $X$ is a normed space, there always exists such a measure.

This case is essentially  $\mathbb{R}^d$, since a Hausdorff locally compact topological vector  space is isomorphic (in the sense of continuous linear bijections) to $\mathbb{R}^d$. You can see why [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1570900/locally-compact-hausdorff-topological-vector-spaces-are-finite-dimensional).

This just solves the case when $X$ is normed, and does not cover all the possible interesting answers.

Perhaps you will also be interested in the theorem about [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure), which regards Borel measures on locally compact groups.

Comment: In the question, $X$ is locally compact, but the vector space is $C_c(X)$; the space of continuous functions with compact support.  And $C_c(X)$ is not a Banach space, is it?

Comment: This is certainly true, IF we are focusing on the case where the measures are bounded in total variation, i.e. $\mu_k(\mathbf{R}^d)$ is bounded independently of $k$. But what about if the measures are allowed to be unbounded (but of course, finite on compact sets by regularity).

Comment: @JacobDenson Here is a simple trick which I often use to geta round the fact that $C_C(X)$ is not Banach: For each fixed compact set $K \subseteq X$ the space $C(X:K):= \{ f \in C_C(X) :supp(f) \subset K \}$ is Banach.... You can now use Banach-Alaoglu theorem for this Banach space and $\mu_n|_{K}$ to argue that this sequence is convergent to a measure, which is supported on $K$. This basically gives you $\mu|_{K}$... The rest is standard:

Comment: You can now define a measure $\mu$ via Riesz-Markov: $$\mu(f):= \mu_{K}(f)$$ where $K$ is any compact such that $supp(f) \subseteq K$. It is easy, but necessary, to check that this definition does not depend on the choice of $K$, and then that by RM it is a measure.

Comment: I did make the mistake of assuming that the measures were bounded, but I think @N.S. comments help solve the problem.

Comment: Does this kind of technique show that the space of all regular Borel measures on a _locally compact space_ is complete under the weak * topology?

Comment: @JacobDenson No, it does not. Duals $(E^*,\sigma(E^*,E))$ of locally convex spaces are in most cases inclomplete -- they are $\sigma(E^*,E)$-dense in the algebraic dual $E^*$ of all (possibly discontinuous) linear functionals on $E$. Sequential continuity, however, is a different story. $(E^*,\sigma(E^*,E))$  is sequentially complete if, e.g., $E$ is a barrelled space.

Comment: Sequential completeness is all I need for my research. But I don't think $C_c(\mathbf{R}^d)$ is a barrelled space, so do we still have sequential completeness?